# Decimal ion-range?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Is it possible to use decimal values such as `33.20` or `2.33` with `ion-range`?

My current code is as follows but it only allows full integers, not decimals but if I change the `ion-range` to an input with a type of `range` the decimal values will show up.

```
<ion-range type="range" min="0" max="30" step="0.01" [(ngModel)]="bolus" color="secondary">
    <ion-icon range-left name="arrow-dropdown-circle"></ion-icon>
    <ion-icon range-right name="arrow-dropup-circle"></ion-icon>
</ion-range>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ion-range round step to integral.

`val = Math.round(val);`

So you have two ways to go: either you modify *"..\node_modules\ionic-angular\components\range\"* or make workaround. For example you can use ratio to calculate decimal value or set max=3000 and then in controller where you using that value divide it by 100.(lets say you have 2553 as value, then when you divide it by 100 you get 25.53)

Comment: `either you modify "..\node_modules\ionic-angular\components\range\"` no , just no dont do this

Comment: The idea with multipling / dividing by 100, that's very smart!